# Packing Project with NuGet in Mono Returns Not Implemented Error

Tags: .net, mono, nuget

I am attempting to package a project with Mono (4.2.1) & NuGet (2.8.5.0). The complete verbose output of the `nuget pack Project.csproj`is

```
Attempting to build package from 'Project.csproj'.
The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`nuget pack project.csproj` is not currently supported on Mono. Please refer to the appropriate [Bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17430).

Using the project file (.csproj) to generate the NuGet package uses parts of MSBuild that are not implemented in Mono. Instead you will need to create a .nuspec file and use `nuget pack YourNuspec.nuspec` to generate a NuGet package with Mono.

Comment: Kind of amazed that I was unable to come up with this through searching around. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is now fixed in nuget and more information can be found in this ticket:
 https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1946

Run the following to update nuget and it will work

**Mac**

```
sudo nuget update -self
```

**Windows**

```
nuget.exe update -self
```